# When did Brandon Routh mention his time as Superman in The Flash?

Tags: reference, arrowverse, the-flash, superman-returns

From Wikipedia page about [Superman curse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_curse)

> Routh eventually played recurring character Ray Palmer (The Atom) on other DC Comics-related projects, Arrow and The Flash. (In The Flash, characters even make veiled references to his time as Superman.)

When did that reference to *Superman Returns* occur in *The Flash* and what was that reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/All_Star_Team_Up#Behind_the_scenes)

> Upon Ray Palmer's arrival Caitlin and Cisco have an exchange when they see something flying in the air. First asking if it's a bird, and then a plane, and Felicity replies that it's her boyfriend. This is a reference to the iconic Superman phrase, referencing Brandon Routh's former title role as Superman in the 2006 film adaptation Superman Returns.

and this happened in the only flash episode Ray Palmer (Atom) appeared in, s01e18, [All Star Team Up](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4138352/)

Answer (score 5):

There was a second joke more recently. When Ray Palmer meets Supergirl in the crossover event, he comments, "She looks like my cousin."

Comment: But that was not the question

Comment: @AnkitSharma Why? Because the crossover episode in question was actually a *Legends of Tomorrow* episode? It still had huge impact on *The Flash* since Cisco finally forgives Barry in it. -- And the fact that **Supergirl** reminds Ray of his cousin is an obvious reference to Brandon having played the role of her cousin (almost so much in your face, it could barely be called veiled anymore).